# How invoke xtend2 generator from java class?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtext, eclipse-emf-ecore, xtend

I use Xtext framwork for my DSL and I want to generate code by a toolbar bottom. 
I get the file selected from workbench but how can I call Xtend generator?
I don't know how I can get the resource param for doGenerate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question was a bit different, my answer holds here as well: [How to invoke Xtext parser/JvmModelInferrer from a Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341342/how-to-invoke-xtext-parser-jvmmodelinferrer-from-a-java-project)

Basically, use the injector Xtext generates and get the IGenerator instance.